# will running my 89 accord without power steering fluid burn out my pump?

Tags: honda, accord, power-steering

The guy I bought my car from rearended somebody and since was leaking power steering fluid so he drained it. Will that burn out the pump

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would assume the answer is: YES. Running it dry cannot be doing it any good. Getting it fixed seems like a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and quickly. Get the problem fixed or it is going to be real, real expensive to replace the pump and maybe the lines plus the power steering rack when the seals, etc. wear out due to lack of lubrication plus it must be a bitch to drive with no Power steering!